# JavaFx Eclipse deploy error applying icon in ant script

Tags: eclipse, javafx, ant

Good morning to everybody, I'm trying to deploy a JavaFx 8 application in Eclipse Neon, runnning the build.xml file as Ant Build. The script generates the following error:

```
Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\iconswap8735143398586032104.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Config files are saved to C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\fxbundler4877222114145654412\windows. Use them to customize package.
Config files are saved to C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\fxbundler4877222114145654412\windows. Use them to customize package.
```

And terminates with the following message:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\PreformTroubleshooting\build\build.xml:129: Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.
```

I'm working on a Windows XP machine and installed the latest version of Java jdk (1.8.0 update 121) for x86 platform. I know this version does not support Windows XP, but the installation seems to work fine (I just got a couple of warning stating the compatibility issue).

I need to deploy my project for older PCs, so I installed InnoSetup to wrap the Java application in a .exe that can be executed by all Windows versions starting from XP.
Can anybody suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by myself, but solved it in a not very elegant way.
The java jdk I use, contains a library ant-javafx.jar which, in turn, contains the exe IconSwap.exe. I extracted it and tried to run in Windows XP, getting the error message. I then replaced only this library with the equivalent taken from jdk version 1.8.0 update 40 and that solved the problem. If anybody has better solution, please advice.
The strange thing is that I downloaded the x86 platform package of the jdk.